# resolvent clause theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

This is about correctness of resolution lemma

Let R be a resolvent of two clauses $C_1$ and $C_2$. Then $C_1, C_2 \models R$.

Proof By definition $R = (C_1 − \{L\}) \cup (C_2 −\{\bar{L}\}) $ (for some L).

Let $A \models C_1$ and $A \models C_2$. There are two cases.

If $A \models L$ then $A \models C_2 − \{\bar{L}\}$  (because $A \models C_2)$, thus $A \models R$.

If $A \not\models L $ then $A \models C_1 − \{L\}$ (because $A \models C_1)$, thus $A \models R$ \

Can someone explain why If $A \models L$ then $A \models C_2 − \{\bar{L}\}$  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There is something wrong*...

> The [resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_propositional_logic) in propositional logic is a single valid inference rule that produces a new clause implied by two clauses containing **complementary** literals.

$C_1$ and $C_2$ are [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) i.e. disjunctions of literals, and a literal is an atom or the negation of an atom.

In order to resolve $C_1$ and $C_2$ with literal $L$ we must have that in one of the clause the literal $L$ occurs negated, i.e. $C_1 := D_1 \lor \ldots \lor L$ and $C_2 := D_2 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot L$.

Thus, the cases are: either $A \vDash L$ or not.

If $A \vDash L$ , due to the fact that $A \vDash C_2$ and $L$ occurs negated in $C_2$, we must have $A \vDash C_2 \setminus \{ \lnot L \}$.

Comment: Thankyou but how do you know that $A \models C_2 - \{\bar{L}\}$? is A clause in here?

Comment: @vedss - if $A \vDash L$ then $A \nvDash \lnot L$. Thus, due to the fact that $A \vDash C_2$ and $C_2 = \ldots \lor \lnot L$, we have that $A \vdash$ the parte of $C_2$ without $\lnot L$, i.e. $A \vDash C_2 \setminus \{  \lnot L \}$

Comment: Oh i see Thankyou!